# ROS documentation "Used By"

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the documentation pages for ROS, found on http://www.ros.org/doc/api/index.html, each file's page has a section labeled "Used By: ". I assumed that this would be a list of files or packages that included this file, either directly or indirectly. However, some files that I know are included in others, such as XnCppWrapper.h, say that they are "Used By: None". What is this section actually supposed to mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10743/ros-documentation-%22used-by%22/) by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"Used by" in the ROS wiki pages and the API documentation is generated from a package's manifest file. There, the package lists its dependencies on other packages for compilation. This list does not have to be complete (as long as the package compiles) and does not extend to all possible headers installed in the system. The API documentation does not give you all files which include the file you are looking at.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2011-07-27**:
To complement Armin's answer, you should also list package dependencies that are needed at run-time, but not at build-time (e.g., packages whose configuration files are being used).